# Storing converted dates in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timezone

I was working on a project and since it is the first one, I didn't know about Mongo storing everything in UTC until I noticed that birthdates were being stored at day X-1 23:00:00 instead of day X 00:00 as it should. I've tried using moment and converting the date to my timezone before storing it but Mongo ignores it.

```
const bdate = moment.tz(body.birthdate, "YYYY-MM-DD", "Europe/Lisbon").format();
```

On console it shows:
`1998-10-20T00:00:00+01:00`

On the database it shows: `"1998-10-19T23:00:00.000Z"`

What can I do to be able to store the data in my local timezone or force MongoDB to show local timezone dates instead?

I've seen solutions using $project to convert into the local timezone but I'd like to get the entire converted date and not just hour/day/month.

Comment: See the answer in the duplicate I linked to.  Basically, whole dates (especially birthdays) should not be given a time or time zone component.  Store what you're given, and don't manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you @MattJohnson for the answer, I searched a lot but I couldn't find a good answer in SO. What about something scheduled that needs a specific date and time?

Comment: If it's a specific date and time in a particular time zone, then conversion to UTC is appropriate.  Store the UTC time, query using UTC times, and convert back to a specific time zone for display.

Answer (score 0):

From mongo docs seems like you can't https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/

They recommend you convert it application side.

I think you should consider how you're going to use the date and how you're going to index the collection.

For example, if your goal is to send the user a notification "Happy birthday" on their birthday at a specific time of day in their local time zone, you might want to bake that time zone shift into what you store in Mongo. That way you can index on the birthdate field, and get all the users you need to notify by querying like `db.users.find({ birthdate: )`. Obviously if the user physically moved time zones this would break (you'd have to update that if they moved). Alternatively you could store their birthday + local timezone as separate fields, but that would make querying it much more complicated.

Comment: `now.getTimezoneOffset()` will be the local time zone offset of where the code is running, not the end user's.   Also, it's never appropriate to construct a `Date` object by adding/subtracting an offset.  Doing so picks a *different* point in time - it doesn't convert it to a different time zone.  The `Date` object's time zone behavior is fixed - it cannot be manipulated.

Comment: @MattJohnson You're right, the example from the Mongo docs is misleading so I editted it out. But your birthday is is actually a different point in time based on what time zone you are in--if I'm in New York my birthday starts 3 hours earlier than if I'm in California. I'm also not sure it is a good idea to store the date as a different type as you suggest in your other answer without looking in to Mongo internals (which I have not). What if you later add an index on the birthdate field? A mongo index on a Date may operate more optimally than on a String or Number.

Comment: It would be good if MongoDB offered a native date-only type.  But AFAIK, they do not.  Still, and index on a number should be fine, and and index on a string will *work* for this as long as the date parts are in descending order of magnitude (`YYYY-MM-DD`), so they are lexicographically sortable.

Comment: @MattJohnson BSON does have a Date type but it seems that it's just a 64 bit integer in the end. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: Both BSON and JavaScript's `Date` type is actually a "date and time in UTC" type. They encode a Unix timestamp.  That's it.  They are misnamed really.  They are more like `Instant` or `Moment` in other APIs.